# Is there a way to organize the list of auto layout positioning constraints?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

The list of positioning constraints does not seem to have much organization. Is there a way to list the constraints in a logical way so as not to have to scan the entire list for a specific item? Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/ViewingandEditingAllLayoutConstraintsforanItemintheSizeInspector.html) which constraints are shown in the list, which can simplify things considerably. I'm not aware of any way of ordering them, however.